# Open chrome extension page programmatically in same tab as website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an chrome-extension-based editor, and I want the user to be able to open a file within the extension when they receive a link like this: `http://myeditor.com/link.html?file=xxxx`

When going to that website I would like that:

- if the person opening the url has the extension, open `chrome-extension://blahblah/?file=xxx`
- else show a read-only version of the file and a link to install the extension.

Now to do that, I have in the link.html file a script that looks like this:

```
    if (window.chrome) {
        if (chrome.app.getDetails() === null) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chromeId, { message: "isInstalled" }, function (reply) {
                if (reply) {
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chromeId, { gotoUrl: document.location.search });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

and in the extension's background.html:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request) {
            if (request.message) {
                if (request.message == "isInstalled") {
                    sendResponse(true);
                }
            }
            if (request.gotoUrl) {
                var url = chrome.extension.getURL(request.gotoUrl);

                chrome.tabs.create({url: url}); // how do I open this in the same tab rather than create a new tab?
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
```

The issue is that the code creates a new tab, is there a way I can open the extension page in the same tab as the page I called it from?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `chrome.tabs.update` instead of `chrome.tabs.create` works fine...